# Exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.PlainXmlWriter+MaxSizeExceededException' was thrown

Tags: .net, wcf

I am getting this error in WCF.  It just started in a service that I reinstalled.  I didn't change any of the config settings.

I've tried increasing maxSizeOfMessageToLog, I've tried commenting out the diagnostics settings in my config, I've tried setting logEntireMessage to false, but it still gives the same error.  I made these changes in the service and client config.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
            <section name="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WELLDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DOC_IMG;Password=DOC_IMG_WELLDEV;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ConversionServerPort" serializeAs="String">
          <value>8093</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ConversionServiceName" serializeAs="String">
          <value>ConversionServer</value>
      </setting>
  </Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionService.Properties.Settings>
        <Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ExpirationProcessInterval" serializeAs="String">
                <value>30</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="CacheItemExpirationTime" serializeAs="String">
                <value>120</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="CacheItemUnloadTime" serializeAs="String">
                <value>60</value>
            </setting>
        </Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\\messages.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging
             logEntireMessage="true"
             logMalformedMessages="true"
             logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
             logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
             maxMessagesToLog="3000"
             maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
      </diagnostics>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="standard">
                    <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="100000"/>
                    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="48" maxConcurrentSessions="30" maxConcurrentInstances="60"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="ConversionBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" listenBacklog="40" maxBufferPoolSize="167772160" maxBufferSize="20971520" maxConnections="40" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520">
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20971520"/>
                    <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="standard" name="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.DocumentConverter">
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://denv0201:8093/ConversionServer" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConversionBinding" name="ConversionServer" contract="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Public.IDocumentConverter"/>
            </service>
        </services>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8093/ConversionServer" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConversionBinding" contract="Tobin.DocumentImaging.Server.ConversionServer.Public.IDocumentConverter" name="NetTcpBinding_IDocumentConverter" />
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: "I've tried increasing maxSizeOfMessageToLog" - to what? Try some ridiculously high value and see if that makes any difference. I believe it is definitely related to WCF logging.

Comment: I'd also try to disable logging from wcf config tool

Comment: I did try increasing the maxSizeOfMessageToLog to a ridiculously high value and it still gave the error.  I also tried commenting out and deleting the diagnostics section in the config to no avail - until I deleted it and then reinstalled the service with the updated config.  Not sure why it had to be taken to that extreme to work...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what's happening is the problem is occurring on the server side and you're checking and changing the client config, or vice versa.

The exception message is definitely related to the size of the message being logged, just check this configuration value on both the server and client.